# how to display 3 latitude & longitude (Marker) in one map?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps

I want to display in google map some location based on my data of longitude and latitude.

here is my data:

```
const result= [[112.30021, 5.5680028],[113.30021, 4.5680028],[114.30021, 3.5680028]]
```

here can see I've 3 latitude and longitude.

i want to display in google map all the location in one secreen.

I'm using react-native-map libraries in my project. So, anyone can help me
how to the Marker for this?

i was tried to get one location to display in map  which is as well not works for me.

please help me to display it in map.

Thanks for your Trying!

```
  return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView
                style={styles.map}
                initialRegion={{
                    latitude: 5.54678,
                    longitude: 116.9087,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
                }}>
                <Marker coordinate={{

                    longitude: result[0][0],
                    latitude: result[0][1],
                }} />
            </MapView>
        </View>
    );
```

Comment: you create 3 markers

Comment: basically it's an array so i want it in a function Array so that that it's given the array in one time

Comment: and how to do the marker for an array, here what've i share is not working for me.

Comment: so, what you've shown doesn't even show one?

Comment: No, doesn't show me anything,Boss!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using map can be solve that problem, i already solve it myself.
In this case:

```
return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView
                style={styles.map}
                initialRegion={{
                    latitude: 5.54678,
                    longitude: 116.9087,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
                }}>{
              result.map((m,id)=>
              <Marker 
              key={id}
              coordinate={{

                    longitude: m[0],
                    latitude: m[1],
                }} />}
                
            </MapView>
        </View>
    );
```